# command line analog of Spy++(Spyxx)

Tags: windows, dialog, spy++

I'm looking for command line analog of Spy++(Spyxx).

In output I expect list of window controls (pushbuttons, checkboxes, etc) like a tree.

For example:

> > [CalcFrame]Calculator[CalcFrame]...[Button]MC
> >
> > [CalcFrame]Calculator[CalcFrame]...[Button]=
> >
> > [CalcFrame]Calculator[CalcFrame]...[Button]1
> >
> > [CalcFrame]Calculator[CalcFrame]...[Button]2
> >
> > ... so on

Could somebody please suggest me something?

Comment: What would a command line version gain over the normal Spy++?

Comment: This makes no sense at all, nobody in his right mind would write a tool like that.  Then again, no motivation given at all.  So you could be first, go for it.  Pretty simple with the winapi EnumXxx and GetClassName functions.

Comment: @JoelLucsy It depends what you want to use Spy++ for... If you're using it for automation purposes, windows messages indicate special events in software which could be really helpful... It would be quite nice to have a Spy++ which could stream data to STDOUT for other applications to hook onto. Far easier than custom made DLL.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable request!  It looks like NirSoft's freeware GUIPropView https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gui_prop_view.html might get you what you want.  Look at the **Save Command-Line Options** on the web page.  (Granted, it says "GUI" but if you provide a save option on the command line, it creates the file and exits without a UI.)